# I get an error using purrr map and quarto

Tags: r, purrr, quarto

I'm trying to run a looped function to use my dataframe (informatio from several states of a country) and create several reports automatically. I'm using map from purrr, to allow the loop to update my .qmd file with a given params, I also create a function called runhtmls that I am trying to called with purrr.
When I run my code for just one variable (the original state name) the html. file renders fine. This is how I set the header of my qmd:

```html
title: "Reportes Automaticos - Excel"
author: "Ariana"
format: 
  html:
    embed-resources: true
    toc: true
    toc-title: "Tabla de Contenidos"
params:
  provincia_nom: "Azuay"
```

And here I'm calling my libraries:

```
#| label: librerias
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, lubridate, stringr, openxlsx, purrr, downloader, readr, haven, kableExtra, writexl, glue, quarto)
```

But, when I call my runhtmls function I'm now getting an error that says:

Error in `purrr::map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error:
! System command 'quarto.exe' failed.

Here is the creation of my function, which is done in a separate R. script:

```html
runhtmls <- function(provincia_nom){quarto::quarto_render("importacion_datos_web_copia.qmd", output_format = "html", execute_params = list(provincia_nom = provincia_nom), 
                                                          output_file = glue::glue("{provincia_nom}.html"))
}

purrr::map(unique(camas_spss_fct$prov_ubi), runhtmls)
```

I'm not sure how to reconcile this error. I've downloaded quarto separately from quarto.org and restarted my computer several times.
Also, do you think that my computer username will represent a problem with the R directory, it is my Hotmail account "aris_"?, I am using Windows btw